# What would happen if you switched the Northbridge and the Southbridge?

Tags: motherboard, northbridge, southbridge

I guess to start, is it even possible? And if not, let's say it was, could it do damage to the Processor or GPU? Could other components on the Motherboard be affected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I guess to start, is it even possible?

Nope. Different chips, different number of pins. Different signals on whatever pins they have. It simply would not work.

Comment: That was easy, kinda figured that's where this would end up lol. Thanks

Comment: The fun part is looking how functions of these chios migrate. From older 386/486 era times and 3 chips tp 2 chip setups (NB & SB) to the current setup with a lot on the chip which used to be purely a CPU on combination with a single chip (atm called a MCH)

Answer (score -1):

i think it can destroy the motherboard and display as well,the board may not even display again

Comment: I really don't find a "I think" answer is very helpful.